# Value not being updated in DB, node.js and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to update the value of my model and it does not work.
The weird thing is that I am printing out the result and it looks different than what I see in my database by using Robomongo.
Any thoughts why this happens?

Here is my code:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  var productId = req.query.product;

  if (productId) {
    Request.createWizard(req.user, { productId: productId }, function(err, request) {
      Product.findById(productId, function(err, product) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('oh no! error', err);
        } else {
          if (product.price =! 0 ) 
            request.status = 'ready';
            console.log(request);
            (Here I see in the terminal: status = ready)
        }  
      });
      req.flash('success', { msg: 'Your request has been successfully created.' });
      res.redirect('/discover');
    });
  } else {
    var pages = require('../../schemas/wizard/request')();
    res.render('requests/form', {
      title: 'Make a Request',
      pages: pages,
      saveState: false
    });
  }
};
```

When I am checking the database status is still on pending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're changing the status property, but you're not saving the document back to the database after doing so:

```
Request.createWizard(req.user, { productId: productId }, function(err, request) {
  Product.findById(productId, function(err, product) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('oh no! error', err);
    } else {
      if (product.price !== 0) {
        request.status = 'ready';
        request.save(function(err) { // <-- save it back to the database
          if (err) {
            console.log('oh no! error', err);
          } else {
            console.log(request);
          }
        });
      }
    }  
  });
  req.flash('success', { msg: 'Your request has been successfully created.' });
  res.redirect('/discover');
});
```